# Font Awesome Web Part header title icon?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, font-awesome

Would anyone know how to use a Font Awesome icon as a web part title icon? rather than using the linked image icon in the web part settings?

This is the code I'm using however the icon only seems to display above the Web Part Title:

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

div#WebPartTitleWPQ2_ChromeTitle:before {
  content: '\f098';
  font-family: fontawesome;
}

[image]

Comment: Try "div#WebPartTitleWPQ2_ChromeTitle a nobr:before" for your selector

Answer (score 0):

The "simplest" but least "automatic" way is to add a Script Editor webpart above the webpart and include the relevant html. Then hide the default webpart title bar.

Obviously you'd need to reference the Font Awesome files and drop them into something like your Style Library. I customized the master page to be able to include fonts anywhere.

I prefer this option because it allows me to customize it the way I want. But if you have to manage deployment on hundreds or thousands of sites/webparts then I understand a more automatic solution may be desirable.

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't work if the code is below the web part?

Comment: Your html inside the script editor is positioned wherever you place it on the page, so if you place it below the webpart, it will show up below the webpart. If that's what you want, then go for it :)

Comment: I have updated my original post - any ideas why the icon displays above the web part title rather than on it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd have to look at the dev tools and fiddle with the css properties a bit to correct that. You could hide the default webpart title and add your own title html ... <h1>... etc. and put the <i class="fa fa...">.. etc. inside the h1 tag. That's what i was suggesting in my original.

Comment: What code would you suggest using to get started?

Comment: <h1 style="display: block; color: #fff; background-color: blue; padding: 4px 8px;"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Archive</h1>

Comment: Thats great thanks, now just need to add font family to the code and Im done! :)